# How to get top n rows from each category in SQL Server without repeating in the next Call

Tags: sql, sql-server

The problem is as follows

I have many categories

```
Category 1:
    Item c-1-1
    Item c-1-2
    Item c-1-3
    Item c-1-4
    Item c-1-5
    Item c-1-6
    Item c-1-7
    Item c-1-8
    Item c-1-9
    Item c-1-10

Category 2:
    Item c-2-1
    Item c-2-2
    Item c-2-3
    Item c-2-4
    Item c-2-5
    Item c-2-6
    Item c-2-7
    Item c-2-8
    Item c-2-9
    Item c-2-10

Category 3:
    Item c-3-1
    Item c-3-2
    Item c-3-3
    Item c-3-4
    Item c-3-5
    Item c-3-6
    Item c-3-7
    Item c-3-8
    Item c-3-9
    Item c-3-10
```

Based on some parameter I need to get n Rows from each category. Once that items are used, then in the next query it should return the items which were not used in the previous call.

For example

In the first round if I take the first 3 rows of each category.

```
C-1-1, C-1-2, C-1-3
```

Then in the second call the next 3.

```
C-1-4, C-1-5, C-1-6
```

So in the fourth execution i need

```
C-1-10, C-1-1. C-1-2
C-2-10, C-2-1. C-2-2
and so on.
```

How to get this in single query of SQL Server? Using rank you can get top 3 of each category. Currently i had to manage using temporary table. Any better solution?

Comment: In single query? How would you return result from SQL server? What format?

In single query per X elements it could be done. Order each category by something so you can track progress. Now make temp table from all those in a way that single row is all those categories in it. So row 1 in temp has row 1 of each table. Make stored procedure that gets  howMany as parameter. Procedure returns howMany rows with select top howMany and deletes em after they are returned. Multiple calls of procedure give you that many rows over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is to select via a cte and row number condition.

```
DECLARE @N INT = 5;
WITH    cte
          AS (SELECT    Sector
              ,         CompanyName
              ,         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Sector ORDER BY CompanyName) RN
              FROM      guid.Companies
              WHERE     Deleted = 0
             )
    SELECT  cte.Sector
    ,       cte.CompanyName
    FROM    cte
    WHERE   RN < @N;
```

This will give you the base details, however to acheive a different set of results I've added a Deleted column, that would need to be set after execution:

```
WITH    cte
          AS (SELECT    Sector
              ,         CompanyName
              ,         Deleted
              ,         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Sector ORDER BY CompanyName) RN
              FROM      guid.Companies
              WHERE     Deleted = 0
             )
    UPDATE    cte
    SET     Deleted = 1
    WHERE   RN < @N
```

The "previously run" info needs to be held somewhere.

Just plug in your table and field names and you should be able to expand from here.

Comment: I've an extra column to notify that it has been used, but the problem is when rolling happens it does not take the first values.

Comment: Can you post the create table code and an insert for some test data so we can see what you are looking at?  Provided the two calls above are executed in that order, things should be fine from what I understand.  Seeing your data will help us advise on the answer.